# CSS position: fixed + mix-blend-mode: difference issue

Tags: html, css, css-position, mix-blend-mode

I am trying to create a sticky nav bar which reacts during scrolling with the background. I experimented with `mix-blend-mode: difference` and it is exactly was I was looking for. But since I am using `position: sticky` or `position: fixed` this is what happen:

Close before hitting the nav bar:
[image: Close before hitting the nav bar]

Here it hits the nav bar:
[image: Here it hits the nav bar]

Unfortunately when it hits the nav bar the whole font is inverting its color. Here is an example how it should look like when it scrolls into each other:

The Hamburger and Logo are creating a nice invert effect:
[image: The Hamburger and Logo are creating a nice invert effect]

In this example I used `position: absolute` and it looks totally fine.

Here is what I have coded so far:

HTML & CSS

```css
.nav-bar {
  width: calc(100vw - 3rem);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.nav-bar ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  top: 200px;
}
.nav-bar ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
.nav-bar ul li img {
  width: 30px;
}
.nav-bar ul li .line {
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.nav-bar ul li .line:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.headline-container {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.headline-container .headline-item {
  width: calc(100vw - 3rem);
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.headline-container .headline-item span {
  font-size: 7vw;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="test">
        <img src="./img/logo_nav.svg" alt="logo" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="headline-container">
  <div class="headline-item">
    <span>W</span>
    <span>E</span>
    <span>B</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>P</span>
    <span>P</span>
    <span>L</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>C</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>T</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>O</span>
    <span>N</span>
  </div>
  <div class="headline-item">
    <span>D</span>
    <span>E</span>
    <span>S</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>G</span>
    <span>N</span>
  </div>
  <div class="headline-item">
    <span>B</span>
    <span>R</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>N</span>
    <span>D</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>N</span>
    <span>G</span>
  </div>
  <div class="headline-item">
    <span>C</span>
    <span>O</span>
    <span>M</span>
    <span>M</span>
    <span>U</span>
    <span>N</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>C</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>T</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>O</span>
    <span>N</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just wanted to edit your post in a way that your code would have got runnable out of the posting. Would result in much better understanding. Unfortunately someone posted already an edit so I couldn't accomplish the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed that issue:

```
<div class="fixed_menu">
    <div class="nav-bar">
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="test">
            <img src="./img/logo_nav.svg" alt="logo" />
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
            <div class="line"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section section1">
    <div class="headline-container">
      <div class="headline-item">
        <span>W</span>
        <span>E</span>
        <span>B</span>
        <span>A</span>
        <span>P</span>
        <span>P</span>
        <span>L</span>
        <span>I</span>
        <span>C</span>
        <span>A</span>
        <span>T</span>
        <span>I</span>
        <span>O</span>
        <span>N</span>
      </div>
      <div class="headline-item">
        <span>D</span>
        <span>E</span>
        <span>S</span>
        <span>I</span>
        <span>G</span>
        <span>N</span>
      </div>
      <div class="headline-item">
        <span>B</span>
        <span>R</span>
        <span>A</span>
        <span>N</span>
        <span>D</span>
        <span>I</span>
        <span>N</span>
        <span>G</span>
      </div>
      <div class="headline-item">
        <span>C</span>
        <span>O</span>
        <span>M</span>
        <span>M</span>
        <span>U</span>
        <span>N</span>
        <span>I</span>
        <span>C</span>
        <span>A</span>
        <span>T</span>
        <span>I</span>
        <span>O</span>
        <span>N</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.section {
 background-color: white;
}

.section1 h1 {
 padding-top: 150px;
 text-align: center;
}

.fixed_menu {
 position: fixed;
 width: calc(100vw - 3rem);
 mix-blend-mode: difference;
 z-index: 2;
 left: 50%;
 top: 30px;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.nav-bar {
 width: calc(100vw - 3rem);
 /* margin: 0 auto; */
}

.nav-bar ul {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 top: 200px;
}

.nav-bar ul li {
 list-style: none;
}

.nav-bar ul li img {
 width: 30px;
}

.nav-bar ul li .line {
 width: 25px;
 height: 5px;
 background: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.nav-bar ul li .line:last-child {
 margin-bottom: 0;
}

.headline-container {
 padding-top: 100px;
}

.headline-container .headline-item {
 width: calc(100vw - 3rem);
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.headline-container .headline-item span {
 font-size: 7vw;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: bold;
 mix-blend-mode: difference;
 color: white;
}
```

I dont know exactly what happened, but since I restructured everything, and used CSS instead of SCSS, i guess i had somewhere a typo, or something like that

Answer (score 0):

For me, this looks like the chromium problem. I use Google Chrome and setting the background color was the solution for me.

Here the [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=711955&q=mix-blend-mode&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
.nav-bar {
  width: calc(100vw - 3rem);
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 40px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
.nav-bar ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  top: 200px;
}
.nav-bar ul li {
  list-style: none;
}
.nav-bar ul li img {
  width: 30px;
}
.nav-bar ul li img .line {
  width: 25px;
  height: 5px;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
.nav-bar ul li img .line:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.headline-container {
  padding-top: 100px;
}
.headline-container .headline-item {
  width: calc(100vw - 3rem);
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.headline-container .headline-item span {
  font-size: 7vw;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="test">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/72XoY.png" width="30px" height="30px" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<div class="headline-container">
  <div class="headline-item">
    <span>W</span>
    <span>E</span>
    <span>B</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>P</span>
    <span>P</span>
    <span>L</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>C</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>T</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>O</span>
    <span>N</span>
  </div>
  <div class="headline-item">
    <span>D</span>
    <span>E</span>
    <span>S</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>G</span>
    <span>N</span>
  </div>
  <div class="headline-item">
    <span>B</span>
    <span>R</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>N</span>
    <span>D</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>N</span>
    <span>G</span>
  </div>
  <div class="headline-item">
    <span>C</span>
    <span>O</span>
    <span>M</span>
    <span>M</span>
    <span>U</span>
    <span>N</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>C</span>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>T</span>
    <span>I</span>
    <span>O</span>
    <span>N</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately that didnt worked out for me.

Comment: I answered "setting the background color" but fotgot to say "of the body element". Did you see and tried this: body { background-color: white; }